# mvc return file xlsx repair needed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc 4 and I'm having some problems with excel files grabbed from the database. I know it's mvc specific, because it doesn't give an error in the normal asp.net part of my code.

When I download my xlsx, it downloads perfectly fine. When opening it, it gives me the following error:

> We found a problem with some content in 'name.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

Obviously I click Yes. There is no problem at all with any of my excel files. They are generated correctly.

Now here's my mvc code:

```
Return File(attachment.FileContent.Content, attachment.FileContent.Type, attachment.Filename)
```

- attachment.FileContent.Content = byteArray with the content
- attachment.FileContent.Type = in this case application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
- attachment.Filename = the filename with the correct ending tag (in this case .xlsx)

However, on my normal asp.net page I don't get this error at all. here's what I do on my asp.net page:

```
Dim filter As IO.Stream = Response.Filter
Response.Filter = Nothing
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = attachment.FileContent.Type
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & attachment.Filename)
Response.OutputStream.Write(attachment.FileContent.Content, 0, attachment.FileContent.Length.Value)
Response.End()
```

If you have any suggestions: I'll gladly acept them.

Comment: no custom action filter that could add some data to the Response Stream ?

Comment: All I do before the code I have given is filling up my attachment model. I don't use any custom filters on this part of my application.